timefold list model,how to set to use tabu_search?
2024-04-02T16:13:34.395+08:00 DEBUG 8 --- [pool-2-thread-1] .EntityIndependentFilteringValueSelector : Bailing out of neverEnding selector (Filtering(FromSolutionPropertyValueSelector(tasks))) to avoid infinite loop.
2024-04-02T16:13:34.402+08:00 ERROR 8 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.app.service.AppService         : Solve error: Move class (class ai.timefold.solver.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.generic.list.ListAssignMove) doesn't implement the getPlanningEntities() method, so Entity Tabu Search is impossible.
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Move class (class ai.timefold.solver.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.generic.list.ListAssignMove) doesn't implement the getPlanningEntities() method, so Entity Tabu Search is impossible.
at ai.timefold.solver.core.impl.heuristic.move.Move.getPlanningEntities(Move.java:151) ~[timefold-solver-core-impl-1.8.1.jar!/:1.8.1]
when using timefold list model,how to set to use tabu_search?

You have not included your solver config, so I can not double-check your configuration is correct. But considering the error message clearly mentions Tabu Search, I'm going to assume the configuration is indeed correct.
In which case, this is a bug. The fix is relatively simple and I will try to get it in for the next release of Timefold Solver.

Thank you! Very much looking forward to the next version with the fixes coming out soon!
